# Was hardware scrolling patented?

Tags: history, hardware, graphics, chip

One of the most valuable graphical features on early computers that had it, was hardware scrolling, that allowed the horizontal position of the screen to be adjusted by one or more pixels, thereby allowing horizontal scrolling to be done more easily than by bit-shifting every byte in the frame buffer or tile bitmaps. The Atari 800 and Commodore 64 had this feature; it greatly improved their quality as game platforms. And it was, as I understand it, cheap to implement (being mostly an 8-bit shift register and some control logic).

Was this technique ever patented? If so, when and by whom?

Comment: Hardware-assisted scrolling of displays existed before home computers, for example the VT100's "smooth scroll". Admittedly the examples I can think of were vertical scrolling, but I can't see that horizontal scrolling is fundamentally different.

Comment: Standard controllers like Motorola 6845 or Intel  8275 did already support hardware scroll in 1977 which by that time was already old - after all, each and every terminal could scroll on it's own :))

Comment: [LInk to 2019 question about 8275](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/what-is-the-history-of-the-intel-8275-video-controller), though no specific details on scrolling.

Comment: I don't really remember horizontal smooth scrolling being a thing. At right edge you wrap to the next line. But **vertical** as noted already in another comment, absolutely! And even though it was really not that important, terminals that did it well seemed so much *nicer* than the ones that just jumped a whole line at once.

Comment: Smooth scrolling on a VT100 seemed sexy, but it was so damned slow, I quickly started turning it off on any terminal I touched.

Comment: @another-dave yes, nice to look at but sucking when doing real work. A waste of time, like much later some OS animated windows growing in stages instead of simply popping up.

Comment: Agree on the lack of purpose of the nice-looking, but entirely useless feature of smooth-scroll on DEC terminals (to me, it was more of an annoyance than a feature). But the question doesn't ask for *smooth* scrolling, but scrolling in general. And that was implemented in hardware much earlier, probably by the earliest video chips. Hardware scrolling on character displays is so easy to implement that everything else was just a waste of CPU.

Comment: I originally brought up 'smooth scrolling' since it seemed to me that had to be hardware-assisted, unlike scrolling by full lines, which arguably could have been done by moving bytes around in some internal RAM buffer.

Comment: @tofro: It's such a shame that DEC didn't offer a mode to scroll at a rate of e.g. 3 or 4 scan lines per frame (about 1/20 or 1/15 second per line), or vary scroll speed based upon the amount of data pending in the input buffer.  On the other hand, if memory serves, many DEC terminals, if they received 150 BEL characters (which would take under a quarter second at 9,600 baud), would beep continuously for the next 15 seconds.  On the other hand, even newer terminal emulators still don't handle such things very well.

Comment: @tofro I'd say even way before any dedicated video chip.